# Is it possible to build linux header a package from a linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, linux-headers

I am not an expert in Linux and that's why I am here.

**My question is: Is it possible to build the corresponding `linux-header-x.xx.xx` package from the original linux kernel?**

Some background:

1. I have an old Linux kernel that is no longer on Ubuntu repo. Therefore, there is no Linux header that I could download easily.
2. I cannot upgrade my Linux kernel because this is a special hardware which uses a mod version of an older Linux Kernel.
3. My only choice seems to be build the HEADER from scratch using the kernel or find somewhere that has the header deb package...

Updates:

- I had a typo. I am looking to build the HEADER from scratch. Not the kernel.

Comment: This site here house the actual still available kernels https://www.kernel.org/

Comment: @Videonauth - I just visited the site, but it seems like there is only the tarball for the kernel. Can I get the headers too?

Comment: The tarball conatains as well the header files under includes, get the patch file too while youre there.

Comment: "I cannot upgrade my Linux kernel because this is a special hardware which uses a mod version of an older Linux Kernel."  Someone needs to cane designers who do stuff like this.  Forcing users to hold onto an unsupported, obsolete kernel isn't just irresponsible, it's negligent.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I agree. This is a sh*t job.

Comment: @Videonauth I can see the include folder but I am not sure how I can build   the "linux-header-x.xx.xxx" package that you can usually do an apt-get with. Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: get one of the newer kernel header packages and unpack the .deb file I would say and you see the structure there how it has to look like. i really can't tell you how they determine where to put all that stuff, in fact you simply need to know hwere they need to go and then copy them in their respective folders

Comment: Just to clarify for someone who might be able to answer -- you need to build a header package that supports the modified kernel your special hardware requires?  But you don't have the source code for the modifications (else you could rebuild a modern, supported kernel package).

Comment: @ZeissIkon I believe the mod version  of the kernel is just slightly different from the original Linux kernel. Furthermore, the linux header that I need is to enable Virtualbox to run. Whatever, modification that was made on that kernel is 99% for the hardware and not for the software. I am trying to use the original kernel to build the header and hopefully that is close enough to run Virtualbox. Finger crossed.

Comment: @Videonauth That seems like a plan. Going to give it a try now!

Comment: Might be easier for the hardware to have an "accident"...  ;)

Comment: @ZeissIkon I don't think I can have accidents on 100s of hardware. LOL.

Comment: Oh.  Okay.  Perhaps you could approach it as "the manufacturer no longer supports this and it's insecure, we need to replace it for security reasons."

Comment: Or make a nice insurance claim after you had a BBQ :p *kidding*